# Passing CLI arguments to excutables with 'go run'

Tags: go

I have a program `readfile.go` and I want to give the command line argument `os.Args[1]` also as `readfile.go`.

However 'go run' thinks that it is an additional argument to itself rather than to the output executable. Is there a flag which can tell 'go run' that this is an argument to executable?

```
mvaidya@mvaidya-VirtualBox:~/junkeork$ go run readfile.go readfile.go
package main: case-insensitive file name collision: "readfile.go" and "readfile.go"
mvaidya@mvaidya-VirtualBox:~/junkeork$
```

Error:

> package main: case-insensitive file name collision: "readfile.go" and
> "readfile.go"

Answer (score 33):

You can use `--` to separate gofiles from arguments:

```
go run readfile.go -- readfile.go
```

Comment: This works, thanks a lot. However, please note that `os.Args[1]` will be `--`, and only `os.Args[2]` will be `readfile.go`

Comment: You can also use the [flag](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) package. `flag.NArg()` and `flag.Arg(i)` get the right arguments whether you used `go generate foo.go -- my args` or compiled `foo.go` and run it as `./foo -- my args` or `./foo my args`. Note that for `flag.Arg(i)` the first (non-flag) argument index is always zero.

Comment: NB: This is how you can pass additional Args. However if you're using `flag` package you should put those flags before the `--`

Answer (score 9):

To avoid the ambiguity of getting twice `readfile.go`, I advise you to use named [flags](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#hdr-Usage). This will solve the problem too.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    cmd := flag.String("cmd", "", "")
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Printf("my cmd: \"%v\"\n", string(*cmd))
}
```

**Don't forget using `flag.Parse()` to retrieve the command line arguments**

You can pass args to the `go run` command this way: `go run .\main.go -cmd main.go` and you'll get as output:

```
my cmd: "main.go"
```

I hope this can help other.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by janos can work well with unnamed args., for named args.:

```
go run [file].go -arg1Name arg1Value -arg2Name arg2Value.....
Eg, go run main.go -x 2 -y 5 ; x and y are arg. names
```