# Go os args consider ".go" as a file path instead of a string

Tags: go

Here's the code where I am basically trying to print base from the path.
Meaning, if the user inputs "/some/random/path.java", the output would be "path". Likewise, if the user arg was "/another/myapp.c" then the output would be "myapp".

This is working for everything except when the input has ".go" as suffix. I am *guessing* that's not working because Go (or visual studio) is actually looking for a file with Go extension?

Code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    inputs := os.Args[1:]
    for _, arg := range inputs {
        fmt.Println(basename(arg))
    }
}

func basename(s string) string {
    // Discard last "/" and everything before
    for i := len(s) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        if s[i] == '/' {
            s = s[i+1:]
            break
        }
    }
    // Discard everything after "."
    for x := len(s) - 1; x >= 0; x-- {
        if s[x] == '.' {
            s = s[:x]
        }
    }

    return s
}
```

How I am executing it:

```
go run main.go "/some/path.java" - this works and the output is "path"
go run main.go "/some/path.go" - this doesn't work and I get an error that says "stat /some/path.go: no such file or directory".
```

Which is a Linux error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing CLI arguments to excutables with 'go run'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45117892/passing-cli-arguments-to-excutables-with-go-run)

Comment: a word on standard nomenclature here:  a "basename" is a file name.  A "dirname" is the path but not the file.  Neither refers to the filename without its "extension".  Note that file extensions in unix are really just part of the file name that happens to follow a `.` and a standard.  So calling "path" the "base" of "path.go" is really quite a poor choice of terms imho

Comment: @DanielFarrell understood and agreed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of running your app with `go run`. You may list multiple source files to `go run` (not just a single one), all will be treated as files of the `main` package.

And since `/some/path.go` "qualifies" to be a `.go` source file, it is not passed to your app but is consumed by the `go` tool.

Build your app first, then run the executable binary, so `go run` will not interfere.

Also note that the first argument that is not a `.go` file name breaks the list of source files, and it with all  subsequent arguments will be passed to your app, even if they are valid `.go` file names.

For example this will pass `/some/path.go` too:

```
go run main.go apple.txt /some/path.go
```

And will output:

```
apple
path
```

Comment: Additionally, unless you're doing this for practice take a look at the [filepath package](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/).

Comment: I was going to suggest `--` but from what I can tell, it's not actually interpreted as separator by `go run`.  It just gets passed as an argument to main.go.  Basically anything other than a `.go` file is passed as an argument - including `--` but also `-b` or `-j` or even just `""` empty string with quotes to protect it from getting interpreted out by the shell

Comment: thank you @icza and thanks everyone else. The issue here is what he suggested, the program needs to compile first.